# Cakephp: Saving the array value not the integer

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

After filtering some data, i created a variable **$customers**. This variable is a simple  array
which has the following values:

```
    array(
        (int) 1 => 'Customer1',
        (int) 2 => 'Customer2',
        (int) 3 => 'Customer3'
    )
```

I passed this array from the controller to the view like this

```
   $this->set('customers', $customers);
```

In the view i use this array in a form so that the user can select one

```
   echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', array('options' => array($customers)));
```

The data which is displayed in the select form is this **'Customer1', 'Customer2', 'Customer3**'

Eveyting works ok so far.

Now, after the user has submited the data, i want to do some further logic in the controller. I want to take the data which the user has selected and save it in a second table. So i do this:

```
   $this->Invoice->set('secondtabel', $this->request->data['Invoice']['customer_id']);
```

The data is being saved in the second table, but the problem is saves the value **'1', '2', '3**' not the name of the customer. How can i save the name of the customer and not the identifier number from the array.

Please bear with me, i am new to cakephp and to php in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is actually a problem with your HTML, your select box likely looks something like this:

```
<select name="customer_id">
    <option value="1">Customer1</option>
    <option value="2">Customer2</option>
    <option value="3">Customer3</option>
</select>
```

This is why your values are 1, 2 or 3 and not Customer1 etc, because `$this->request->data['Invoice']['customer_id']` is equal to 1, 2 or 3 etc.

My suggestion would be to fix this at the root of the problem, and I think that by **only passing the values** into your select box, you should get HTML like this:

```
<option>Customer1</option>
```

... which will mean that `$this->request->data['Invoice']['customer_id']` will equal `Customer1` etc.

**So, try this:** (array_values will return an array only containing the values, essentially stripping the keys)

```
$this->set('customers', array_values($customers));
```

This should fix your problem. However, as far as structured data goes, the way you are currently doing it (storing 1, 2 or 3 etc) is actually the correct way to do this. This way, you simply **join** the customers table when you are retrieving this data, and you can grab the name that way... Something like this:

```
$invoices = $this->Invoice->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        // your custom find conditions
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'customers',
            'alias' => 'Customer',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Customer.id = Invoice.customer_id')
        )
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Invoice.*', // retrieve regular invoice data
        'Customer.name' // retrieve the joined customer name too
    )
));
```

This way you still store a customer ID as an integer, and simply look up the name with SQL when you go to retrieve that data.

A possible reason why you might want to do it simply by storing the customer's name as text is that you want to store the customers name **as it appears at the time**, meaning if it changes in the future, previous invoices with that name attached won't change with it because that name is stored in text rather than a numeric reference to another table containing a name that **has** changed.

Hope this helps.

> Docs

- http://php.net/array_values

Comment: Thank A LOT @scrowler. Your explication is so good and the suggestion about joining the tables is right on spot :) You are my hero today